# Datetime format in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my aplication I use a `DateEdit` control and show the date using this format `dd/MM/yyyy` so the date is save correctly when I use mssql-server 2014 (spanish) but whe I use mssql-server 2008 (english) the date is stored with this fomat `MM/dd/yyyy` so what I need to know is **if there is a way to store the date with the format `dd/MM/yyyy` no matter the versión of mssql-server I use or the lenguage I use?**

**EDIT:** to explain better this is the problem, this text `03/07/2017` is stored in the sqlserver 2014 as july 3 of 2017 and in the sqlserver 2008 is stored as march 7 of 2017.

Comment: Dates do not have a format; formats are just how the value is displayed to humans.  use date columns and pass date variable types and all will be well

Comment: Dates aren't exactly "stored" the way you think they're stored. Dates are just numbers that increment from 01/01/1900 (the same with times, but times increment from midnight). If you _always_ want to display your dates in a given format when using `SELECT`, you might look at the page on [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) (under "Date and Time styles").

Comment: `this text 03/07/2017 is stored in the sqlserver 2014 as july 3 of 2017`  only if you are fetching and passing **text**.  Pass a **date** and save it in a **date** column.  Leave "formatting" to the UI layer

Comment: How you are saving your date in MSSQL server? There is no code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the defualt language on your MS SQL Server 2008, and if its possible, you can change to Spanish: [How to change Date Format after installing SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/)

Also, you can format your query output with the CONVERT function (@ZLK post the link) using the format 103: `CONVERT (DATETIME,[YOURDATE],103)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(String).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solution has two options. You can use one as per your requirements.

```
DECLARE @Date AS TABLE(val VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO @Date VALUES('12/04/2016');
INSERT INTO @Date VALUES('10/01/2015');
INSERT INTO @Date VALUES('17/03/2017');

--Option 1
SELECT TRY_PARSE(val AS DATE USING 'en-gb') 'Option 1' FROM @Date;

--Option 2
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRY_PARSE(val AS DATE USING 'en-gb'),103) 'Option 2' FROM @Date;
```

And the outputs are:

[image]

Comment: Or at least this solution should give you an idea that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

As others said: SQL doe not store dates as we humans do. But thats another matter. 
I think what you need is to inform SQL the format your date has.
The best option is to use ISO 8601 format: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm. 
So, if before saving the date you just format it with this format, SQL (no matter the version or the language) will recognize it as begining with a year, followed by a month and so on. **The key of this subject is using first 4 digits**. 
This way, *2017-01-03* will always be *January 03, 2017* and never *March 01, 2017*. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can change the date Format

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy', 'en-us')
```